# How to handle CXProviderDelegate function for both Voice and Video in Twilio app?

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, callkit

In my app I've implemented both Voice and Video. How do I distinguish CXProviderDelegate functions for voice and video? I've CXProviderDelegate defined in AppDelegate.

Do I need to identify voice and video inside each of these delegates?

or

Create two set of delegates, one for Voice and another for Video?

I'm using following code
Twilio voice https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-swift 
Twilio Video https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-swift

Following is code example:

**Voice**

```
extension AppDelegate: CXProviderDelegate {

    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {
        NSLog("provider:performAnswerCallAction:")

        assert(action.callUUID == self.callInvite?.uuid)

        TwilioVoice.isAudioEnabled = false
        self.performAnswerVoiceCall(uuid: action.callUUID) { (success) in
            if (success) {
                action.fulfill()
            } else {
                action.fail()
            }
        }

        action.fulfill()
    }
}
```

**Video**

```
extension AppDelegate : CXProviderDelegate {
    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {
        logMessage(messageText: "provider:performAnswerCallAction:")

        self.audioDevice.isEnabled = false;

        self.audioDevice.block()

        performRoomConnect(uuid: action.callUUID, roomName: self.roomTextField.text) { (success) in
            if (success) {
                action.fulfill(withDateConnected: Date())
            } else {
                action.fail()
            }
        }
    }
}
```